# IE 8/9 not render header background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap theme, the header background image not shown(displayed as black) in IE 8/9 but all other browsers displayed correctly

CSS:

```
.navbar-fixed-top { 
   background: url(http://i47.tinypic.com/15ed8ub.jpg) repeat-x;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .nav { 
   margin:12px 0 0 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue (if trying to put the image in the `.brand` container) is that you need to set the dimensions of the image for IE.

For example:

```
.brand img{
  width:238px;
  height:50px;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: i am new to css, i want that image horizontally repeat in the header

Comment: now i removed background image and set the color as #0A3A6B now works fine in IE